# iMac 2011 and WiFi 5GHz problem

Tags: wifi, imac

I have a problem with a Wi-Fi 5GHz connection on my iMac.

I configured the 5 GHz network in the network settings, but iMac doesn't discover it. Usually it is connected to the 2.4 GHz network, and drop-down menu of Wi-Fi networks doesn't show 5 GHz mode. Sometimes, when booting, iMac sees and can connect to the 5 GHz network.

As a result of analysis of the problem, I realized that it depends on the region in the Airport utility. In the utility I selected US as a country. A Wi-Fi adapter determines himself is in Russian. 5 GHz radio is not for Russia (802.11d), so the adapter just does not see the existing network in most cases. Sometimes, at the next boot, the adapter does not set RU, and thus sees and connects to the 5 GHz network.

Tell me, please, how you solve a similar problem.

PS: The problem is well known and is described in Internet. iMac is only problem, a MacBook and an iPhone connected to 5GHz without problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I did some sleuthing and found my 2.4 GHz network was actually faster than the 5GB in certain parts of my house ... on MacBookPro mid-2010 and iPad 2 wi-fi. Airport Extreme Base Station.

So possibly, depenoing on placement of your machine, it's not a big problem?

Comment: Yes, it's not so important and 2.4 is enough. But would be nice for modes between devices. Here's a screenshot: http://gyazo.com/e033cee8cea8c4a04c045ca65fe9891c
I rebooted iMac and now I see 5 GHz and using it.

Comment: Have you tried setting network to no password, temporarily? Or opening Guest? When Lion came out, it was so bad, people were downloading iStumbler and similar to connect. Once established, then Airport Utility could cope.

Comment: No, I don't. I'll try to set these options.

Comment: Finally, I'm not sure the cause of it. Think about hardware's misunderstoods for channel, region, etc. Thanks.